# How to transform csv list to int?

Tags: python, csv

Here is a code i created before.

```
import sys,csv
from matplotlib import pyplot
from time import sleep
import numpy as ma
import pandas
import serial
file = open("C:/Users/rickchen/Desktop/MQTT1/testfile.csv")
book = csv.reader(file)
b=list(book)
print b
print type(b)
```

I found that the result is like that

```
[['114', '119', '116', '118', '120', '118', '113', '118', '121', '122', '117', '114', '112', '114', '115', '120', '128', '128', '120', '112', '110', '117', '122', '118', '112', '113', '122', '120', '116', '114', '118', '117', '128', '132', '130', '112']]
<type 'list'>
```

It's string, and can not be used to be plotted.

so, I figure out a new code to solve this problem

```
import sys,csv
from matplotlib import pyplot
from time import sleep
import numpy as ma
import pandas
import serial
file = open("C:/Users/rickchen/Desktop/MQTT1/testfile.csv")
book = csv.reader(file)
b=list(book)
c=[]
for bx in b:
    c.append(int(bx))
print c
print type(c)
```

but, it shows TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

So, I want to know how to solve this problem. Does master can give me some suggestion? Thank you so much!!

Comment: `b = [int(e) for e in b]`

Comment: `book = [int(line.strip()) for line in csv.reader(file)]` should work directly.

Comment: Isn't the `.strip()` pointless?

Answer (score 0):

Your list result contains another list, you need to iterate both of them :

```
c = [int(val) for list1 in b for val in list1]
```

Your code could be converted to this :

```
with  open("C:/Users/rickchen/Desktop/MQTT1/testfile.csv") as file:
    book = csv.reader(file)
    c = [int(val) for list1 in book for val in list1]

print(c)
```

(using `with` as context manager avoid to close the file at the end)

Comment: @陳俊良 i'm not sure how you want to plot this next, don't you need to get the results row by row from your csv ?

Answer (score 0):

As we can notice in your output, b is a list of list. So when bx will be a list too and not int.Consequently, you must take only the first element of the b list and our code is modified as below :

```
import sys,csv
from matplotlib import pyplot
from time import sleep
import numpy as ma
import pandas
import serial
file = open("C:/Users/rickchen/Desktop/MQTT1/testfile.csv")
book = csv.reader(file)
b=list(book)
c=[]
for bx in b[0]:
   c.append(int(bx))
print c
print type(c)`
```